# how to change kafka rest proxy log level

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

i am using apache kafka rest proxy using docker compose and it makes heavy log file heavier than my massages size i there any parameter to set or something to do to disable this ?

```
 kafka-schema-registry:
 image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
 hostname: kafka-schema-registry
 ports:
   - "8082:8082"
 environment:
  SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
  SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: kafka-schema-registry
  
  SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8082
  depends_on:
   - zookeeper
   - kafka

kafka-rest-proxy:
 image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:latest
 hostname: kafka-rest-proxy
 ports:
   - "8083:8083"
 environment:
  # KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zoo1:2181
  KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8083/
  KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://kafka-schema-registry:8081/
  KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: kafka-rest-proxy
  KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
  - kafka
  - kafka-schema-registry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KAFKA_REST_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL` defaults to `INFO` and can be changed to `WARN` or `OFF`.

To set additional loggers to specific levels, you may set
`KAFKA_REST_LOG4J_LOGGERS`

Source - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-images/blob/master/kafka-rest/include/etc/confluent/docker/log4j.properties.template